# Open/close app when touchpad is enabled/disabled

Tags: touchpad

Mostly, I use my laptop in a desk, with a wireless mouse. But, sometimes, I obviously need to ditch this mouse and use the laptops' touchpad.

When I do so, I like to use an app called "Touchpad Blocker", which basically blocks any touchpad action while typing (which is useful to avoid accidental clicks and stuff like that).

So, my question is: is it possible to open and close that specific app whenever I enable and disable the touchpad? I guess this could be done using AutoHotKey or something alike, but I have no clue on how to do it.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: You may be able to write a bat or powershell script to do this. Either way, this site will help you if you get stuck so try something first and then we can help at a specific problem

Comment: I actually have no clue on how to write a bat or powershell.